# Compilation errors using shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

My application is returning an error:

```
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:5: error(#132) Syntax error: 'out' parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

whenever I execute the following code:

**fragment.fs**

```
#version 330

in vec4 color

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = color;
}
```

**vertex.vs**

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

out vec4 color;

uniform float uniformFloat;

void main() {
    color = vec4(clamp(position, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon after `in vec4 color` in the fragment shader.

Comment: Yes! Cannot believe I missed that! Thank you, I'm new to programming in GLSL.